# How to identify in which record the validation failed using WCF and EntLib Validation Block?

Tags: .net, wcf, validation, enterprise-library

#### Problem:

I have a WCF Webservice which can be used by customers to upload multiple datarecords. To validate the data I use Enterprise Library Validation Block. The records can be nested several layers deep.

#### Question:

How to identify in which record the validation failed?

#### Example:

Consider the following datastructure. For each Continent there can be multible Countries and for each Country there can be multiple Cities.

- Continent

  - Name
  - Country

    - Name
    - City

      - Name
      - Mayor

When the validation of the Mayor of a City fails, I want to know for which City, Country and Continet it failed.

Comment: Are you getting the "creator of this fault did not specify an exception" message?

Comment: Sortof. I modified the integration to replace that ugly message with one of the details similar to whats proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164602/wcf-entlib-validation-change-default-soap-fault-reason-text/1165843#1165843

And this message is being shown as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved my problem by doing the following:

### Setup int the WCF Integration:

`(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF)`

#### Create a simple marker Attribute:

```
public class ValidationKeyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

which will be put on the Property that identifies the data record.

#### Create an Interface:

```
public interface IValidationBackReference
{
    object BackReference { get; set; }
}
```

This is for the reference from the City record to the Country record in the above example so that all Identifiers up the chain also get included

#### Modify the `BeforeCall()` Method in `ValidationParameterInspector`

to crawl all inputs and set the `BackReference` using something like this:

```
private void SearchForBackReferences(object input, object backReference)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Type t = input.GetType();
    if (t.IsArray)
    {
        Object[] inputs = (object[])input;
        SearchForBackReferences(inputs, backReference);
    }
    else if (input is IValidationBackReference)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in t.GetProperties())
        {
            object value = info.GetValue(input, null);
            SearchForBackReferences(value, input);
        }
        ((IValidationBackReference)input).BackReference = backReference;
    }
}

private void SearchForBackReferences(object[] inputs, object backReference)
{
    if(inputs==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (object input in inputs)
    {   
        SearchForBackReferences(input, backReference);
    }
}
```

#### Modify the `CreateValidationDetail` method in `ValidationParameterInspector`

to go up the record tree via the BackReferences with something like this

```
private static string FindKey(object target)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if( target == null )
    {
        return result.ToString();
    }
    if(target is IValidationBackReference)
    {
        result.Append(FindKey(((IValidationBackReference) target).BackReference));
    }
    Type t = target.GetType();
    foreach (var info in t.GetProperties())
    {
        if (Attribute.IsDefined(info, typeof(ValidationKeyAttribute)))
        {
            object objectValue = info.GetValue(target, null);
            string stringValue = "(null)";
            if (objectValue != null)
            {
                stringValue = objectValue.ToString();
            }
            result.Append(string.Format("{0} = '{1}'; ",info.Name, stringValue));
        }
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

and put it into the `Details.Key` of the `ValidationKDetail`. So far the Setup.

---

### In the Webservice

all you have to do now is Implement the `IValidationBackReference` interface on the classes used by the Webservice and put the `[ValidationKey]` Attribute on appropriate Properties.

The example above would look like:

```
public class Continent : IValidationBackReference
{
    public object BackReference { get; set; }
    [ValidationKey]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country[] Countries{ get; set; }
}

public class Country : IValidationBackReference
{
    public object BackReference { get; set; }
    [ValidationKey]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public City[] Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City : IValidationBackReference
{
    public object BackReference { get; set; }
    [ValidationKey]
    public string Mayor { get; set; }
}
```

what a monster ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to write your own validator that would contain the logic necessary to go back up your object tree and produce a suitable validation error message. Take a look at this article for more info:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VABCustomValidator.aspx